# Rails: rake task with arguments not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, zsh, rake-task

Here is my rake task

```
namespace :users do
  task :change_role, [:role] => :environment do |t, args|
    puts args.role
  end
end
```

I am calling it like this:

`rake users:change_role["role"]` but I am getting this error `no matches found: users:change_role["role"]`

Comment: Where are you putting this? There's nothing wrong with what you've written, or how you're invoking it.

Comment: does your rake task file has file extension as .rake?

Comment: @nickcen - my file is named `users.rake`

Comment: @meagar - it's in `app/lib/tasks`

Answer (score 62):

You need to escape the square brackets when using them in some shells like zsh:

```
rake users:change_role\["role"\]
```

Comment: No it is not.  That is the error from your shell telling you there are no matches for that command found. With zsh and no escaping the output is `zsh: no matches found: users:change_role[ok]`. Using zsh with escaping the output is `ok`

Comment: You're correct, its rake saying it can't find the command.  In any case, you need to escape the brackets with zsh.

Comment: Ah, actually I think you're right. "No matches found:" is definitely *not* being output by rake; rake would have said "don't know how to build task...".

Comment: That escaping isn't correct... I tried this `rake users:change_roles[\"hello\"]` and I am still getting the same error

Comment: Did you mean `rake users:change_role[\"hello\"]`?

Comment: Great call! the full error is indeed: `zsh: no matches found:`

Answer (score 31):

Put the rake task in single quotes.

```
rake 'users:change_role["role"]'
```

more on https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-use-arguments-in-a-rake-task

Comment: The only thing that works for me (Rails `5.0.7.2`)!!

Comment: This is a zsh prereq.

Comment: we should ask the OP if he is using zhs or not. But this helped me, as I just switched to zhs.

Answer (score 10):

You can add `unsetopt nomatch` to your .zshrc file, as Chad Pytel describes in [here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-use-arguments-in-a-rake-task)

Comment: You the man, dog. This is the right answer for most people, especially those that are coming from `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

@infused way works, but if you want change to be permanent, so you can simply call `rake users:change_roles["hello"]`, add following to your .zshrc:

```
alias rake='noglob rake'
```

Comment: this is working fine with me on Ubuntu 20.4, thank you