# How can I configure Rails with Neo4j in an existing repo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, neo4j.rb

I'm currently trying to re-configure my database to use Neo4j as opposed to Postgres and I'm having issues with configuration.

I've adding the `neo4j` gem into my gemfile as well as `neo4j-core`,
`neo4j-ruby-driver`, and `neo4j-rake_tasks`.
I've tried running `rake neo4j:install[community-latest]` to generate the Neo4j instance but it throws me this – `zsh: no matches found: neo4j:install[community-latest]` After listing all rake tasks this rake task does not appear to be present despite every online resource demonstrating this as the way to generate the DB.
I'm currently running on rails version `6.1.3.2` and ruby version `2.6.6`

These are some of the resources I have been using.

1. https://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/v10.0.1/Setup.html
2. https://diatomenterprises.com/using-neo4j-with-ruby-on-rails/

Many thanks in advance

Comment: maybe the gem `neo4j-rake_tasks` has not been installed yet, you could try `bundle install` first, you also could list available rake tasks by run command `rake -T`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails: rake task with arguments not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24558899/895789)

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with the zsh shell misinterpreting the brackets in the command line.

Use single quotes to escape the argument. Example:

```
rake 'neo4j:install[community-latest,development]'
```